# Why is it that when I put a hyphen(-) in an input, it is sent to the database as a question mark?

Tags: javascript

For example, when in my input in html i put a "`testing - test`" and i send this to my database in Oracle the register is like that : "`testing ¿ test`" . Why is this happening? I'm using javascript and Spring. Maybe is something of the configuration?

```
var minimoUnaLetra = /[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d10-9]+/
        var denominacionComercial = $("#denominacionComercialTicket").val(); 
        if(denominacionComercial != ""){
            if(!minimoUnaLetra.test(denominacionComercial)){
                toastr.error("La denominación comercial debe contener, por lo menos, una letra o un número.");

                valido = false;
            }
            console.log("ANTES " + denominacionComercial);
            if(denominacionComercial.includes('–')){ 
                denominacionComercial.replace('–','-');
                console.log("DESPUÉS " + denominacionComercial);
            }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Oracle, but it sounds like a character encoding issue (in SQL it's called collation)

Comment: I see it's not easy to fix that

Comment: Yeah, won't be easy, you'll have to do it anyway. The JS side is usually not relevant, since it uses the proper encoding by default, please show us your Spring configuration, Java code responsible for handling requests and DB connections, and the Oracle configuration.

Comment: Did you mean to do `denominacionComercial = denominacionComercial.replace('–','-');` to eliminate a "long" hyphen?

Comment: @James yeah i tried this because i was expecting it was a JS problem, but it's not working. so i guess it's Spring problem or DB

Comment: Yeah but you didn't assign the result back to denominacionComercial, so the change didn't happen.  Try that before delving into oracle stuff.